# Spring Boot upgrade to 2.4.13 deployed to websphere 8.5.5 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.setContentLengthLong

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlets, websphere

When i try to upgrade an application to spring boot 2.4.13 and deploy to websphere 8.5.5 it gives me below error.`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.setContentLengthLong(J)V (loaded from file:/apps/WebSphere85/AppServer/ plugins/javax.j2ee.servlet.jar by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@ede7c06f) called from class org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse (loaded from file:/applis/196233/was/app_name/installedApps/ app.ear/app-war.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-5.3.20.jar by`

I force pushed the servlet 3.1.0 in pom.xml to avoid it using from parent class loader. still it is always taking jar from parent class loader.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

It is working with earlier version of spring boot 2.1.3.RELEASE. we were not suppose to upgrade the servlet to 3.1.0 in server as it is used by different applications. please advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a workable scenario. While you can override many of the server-provided APIs in an application running on a WebSphere server, Servlet is not one of them - the web container must link to the version of the API within the server, and there's no way for an application to separately use that API without class conflict issues. If you hadn't hit a NoSuchMethodError, you'd instead run into a ClassCastException when the web container attempts to cast your application's Servlet class to the internal instance of the API.

WebSphere 9 supports Java EE 7 (including Servlet 3.1), and Liberty supports versions all the way up to the latest Jakarta EE specs, so if moving to a newer server version is possible, that would work. If you're locked to 8.5.5, though, you'll have to stick with a version of Spring that supports Servlet 3.0 at the latest.

Comment: Thanks Jarid. For WebSphere Liberty can we manually override the Servlet version 3.1.0 via application class loader from the one present in parent class loader ( 3.0.1). If not, how to use the Servlet version 3.1.0 in liberty? Thanks for the response.

Comment: You can't override the provided Servlet version at the application level in Liberty, either (and frankly I'd be surprised if you could do it in any Java/Jakarta EE application server) - the web container must be linked to the same instance of the API as the application in order for the container to handle the application objects. Regardless, Liberty supports Servlet API versions from 3.0 through 5.0, by declaring the necessary version of the feature in the server.xml (see https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/feature/servlet-3.1.html for details on 3.1).

Comment: some other application which had been deployed to same server with same spring boot version 2.4.13 is working fine without above issues. any idea how it could be possible

Comment: Pretty much impossible to tell with certainty... my best guess is that the working app with 2.4.13 manages to do its work without calling any methods that were added in Servlet 3.1. As long as it doesn't call any new methods (which, as you saw, will cause a NoSuchMethodError), it likely can tolerate the older version.